# How to update view after deleting record in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view inside which i am **saving records to the database** and **showing that records with Viewbag variable on same page** i have a delete button in front of each record to delete records, i want after deleting the record the view should get updated how to achieve that

My controller method

```
   public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        db.Delete<Logs>(id);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id });
    }
```

My html and query

```
<button type="button" id="delete" data-id="@item.LogId" class="delete btn btn-default" style="background-color:transparent"><i class="fas fa-times h3" style="color:red;"></i></button>

        $('.delete').click(function () {
            var selectedid = $(this).data("id");
            $.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "Log")", { id: selectedid });

        });
```

Comment: You can use partialview to achieve this, on click of delete you can delete and get the partialview updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should know is `RedirectToAction` won't work in AJAX call, you should pass URL to redirect with `location.href` as follows:

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    db.Delete<Logs>(id);

    // other stuff

    string url = this.Url.Action("Index", "Log", new { id = id });

    return Json(url);
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "Log")", { id: selectedid }, function (result) {
    window.location.href = result;
});
```

Or better to create a partial view that contains all elements to be updated via AJAX and pass it into `success` part afterwards:

**Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    db.Delete<Logs>(id);

    // other stuff

    return PartialView("PartialViewName");
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$.post("@Url.Action("Delete", "Log")", { id: selectedid }, function (result) {
    $('#targetElement').html(result);
});
```